# I have error when I try to run my project on my real device

Tags: android, flutter

I try to run my project on my device and I get this error:
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

`adb: failed to install E:\flutter-file\chat_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1346042202.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #7): Requires newer sdk version #28 (current version is #25)] Error launching application on SM J250F.`

Answer (score 2):

1. Please use latest android studio
2. In an Android Studio project, you have to edit the `build.gradle` file. In a flutter project, it is found at the path `./android/app/build.gradle`.

You can use flutter.targetSdkVersion as targetSdkVersion.
So you don't need to keep manually update it every time.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdk 19 
    //This is the part that needs to be changed, previously was 25
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}
```

Please keep follow goole latest policy.
[Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk)
New apps must target Android 12 (API level 31) or higher; except for Wear OS apps, which must target Android 11 (API level 30) or higher.

Starting in November 2022, app updates must target API level 31 or above and adjust for behavioral changes in Android 12.